# Can I create a Mac like menu in CSS 3?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

See the menu where it says Home. Can this menu bar be replicated using CSS 3 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using

- [rounded corders](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)
- [gradients](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)
- [border](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)
- [text shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/)

Checkout a [full example](http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/06/29/getting-sassy-with-css/).

Answer (score 0):

Easily. For example, you could do a horizonal `ul` with a gray-gradient background and a class that has something like `background: #b3c0d0`, `border-radius: 10px` and `color: white`.